# When is it possible to split an infinite sum?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, summation

I know ordering of terms matters for conditionally convergent sums, so must the sums be absolutely convergent to be able to split like so:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n + \frac{1}{n^2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_n + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ exists and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$ exists, then the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (a_n + b_n)$ exists and is equal to $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n +\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$

---

You can easily show this by using two facts:

1. $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = \lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$$
2. If the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n$ exists and the limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$ exists, then the limit of $\{a_n+b_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ also exists and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n + b_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n + \lim_{n\to\infty} b_n$$

Comment: In other words: when your sum converges you are allowed to split it into two convergent sums.

Comment: @M.Winter Actually, it's "when your sum can be split into two convergnent sums, it converges".

Comment: Yes, but in this formulation it is the other way around as what OP asks for. And mine is still correct.

Comment: @M.Winter: What about $\sum(n-n)$? Is it convergent? Can you split it?

Comment: @Asaf Of course. E.g. into $\sum_i q^i$ and $\sum_i-q^i$ for $|q|<1$.

Comment: @M.Winter: Yes, but it doesn't split into $\sum n+\sum(-n)$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila $\sum \pm n$ does not converge. I said you are allowed to split it into *convergent sums*. You have to check the convergents of the split-sums by yourself. Maybe my formulation was a bit inaccurate.

Comment: @AsafKaragila M. Winter never claimed it does. The comment they made was completely correct - if a sum converges, you are allowed to split it into two convergent sums. You present a case of two non-convergent sums, so you aren't really adressing the original comment.

Comment: @M.Winter: But then it's a useless claim, since you can always write $\sum a_n=\sum(a_n+0)=\sum a_n+\sum 0$.

Comment: @Asaf That's true. It is no deep result. I just wrote the statement of 5xum's answer in a ways in which I thought it would adress OP's question. OP is allowed to split a convergent sum $\sum_i(a_i+b_i)$ into $\sum_ia_i$ and $\sum_ib_i$ if both converge.

Comment: @5xum: If one wishes to argue a "technically correct" claim, at least one should make sure it is not "technically trivial". :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila It's not technically trivial, it is technically exactly what OP was asking in the first place.

Comment: @5xum: See my previous comment to M. Winter. If you just claim that there is a decomposition, then you made a trivial claim, since you can make a lot of trivial decompositions which tell you absolutely nothing.

Comment: @AsafKaragila But if the question is "under what circumstances is a decomposition valid" (which is probably closer to what OP was asking than the title of his post), then Winter's comment is exactly what OP was asking for...

Comment: @5xum: The reason I hate so much talking to mathematicians is that they will entirely ignore the true context of whatever said and treat only the syntactic version of what was said. Of course the OP meant to ask when we can split a representation of a convergent series. Otherwise the answer is always yes, in all manner of trivial splittings. I wonder if people like that respond to their infant children by "syntax incorrect. Ignoring." when they speak incorrectly, or if they read between the mistakes to understand what their child wanted to say.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am probably misunderstanding your comment, because to me, it looks like you are doing the exact thing you say I am doing - you claim that Winter's answer is technically trivial, when in fact, it exactly answers OP's question --- but the question OP **wanted** to ask, rather then the one they actually asked (which, as your $\sum a_i = \sum(a_i+0)$ point shows, is trivial).

Comment: @5xum: There is no contradiction. I am a mathematician, like the rest of them annoying folks, I too, can't help it. But I can complain about it... :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila If it's worth anything, your comment made at least one mathematitian laugh. Well, when I say laugh, it's more "slighly increase the voume of air expelled through my nose", but still.

Comment: Most entertaining thread in forever.

Comment: @5xum: I believe that the technical term you're looking for is "chuckle", "snicker" or "snigger". Technically a type of laughter, but it is best to be accurate when possible. :P

Comment: I have an actual question haha, if we can write an infinite sum $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_i| - \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|b_i|$, and $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|b_i| < \infty$ but $ \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_i|  = \infty$, does this show that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}x_i = \infty$? Intuitively it seems like it should but I know intuition is not good with infinite sums

Comment: @user428487, yes, then it diverges. Try writing $a_i = (a_i + b_i) - b_i = x_i - b_i$, and check what happens if $a_i$ does not converge. By the contradiction with the fact that the limit of sum is the sum of limits you prove that if one component is divergent, and second is convergent, then the sum convergent. This proof is given in Apostol Calculus 1.